# Do you have to use all four accounts right away for Xbox Live Gold family memberships?

Tags: xbox-360, xbox-network

I checked Microsoft's FAQ for the Xbox live gold family pack, and browsed on here for a  little while, but can't seem to find the answer to my question.  My wife and I both have Xbox consoles, and I was wondering if I bought the family pack, do I have to add four different accounts right away, or if my wife and I could both use two memberships. So we would both have 24 months total.  I know this is probably not the case because Microsoft probably would not allow that, but I just thought I'd ask.

Comment: Can you please edit the description to clarify the "or if I we could" part, and elaborate on your question about using two memberships?

Comment: sorry about the typo... I just meant could I double up on two of the memberships. Like could I use two and my wife use two.  Like 24 months right away.  But I guess they all start counting down right away.  So by the time I needed the other membership it would already be expired.

Answer (score 1):

The memberships in the gold pack all start on the date of purchase. You don't have to assign them all at once, but the timer is ticking as soon as you buy.

Unfortunately, the only place that they tell you this is one small line on the this [page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing-and-subscriptions/account-management/how-to-join-family-pack):

> Note Your Gold Family Pack membership starts on date of your purchase. Your credit card is charged immediately, after any discounts are applied

If you need to add somebody after the fact, this [page](http://support.xbox.com/en-US/billing-and-subscriptions/parental-controls/managing-family-members) should help you out. Even if you only need two of the memberships, it's still a better deal than buying them full price, but the unique billing system for them might make it worth just buying two of them.

Comment: OK thank you very much. That was very helpful because I couldn't find that info anywhere on Microsoft's website... go figure.  Any way I'll probably just wait until I find a 12 month membership on sale for $40.  They do that every couple of months.